# Can spring execute a factory bean on @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

If I have a Spring webapp, with an endpoint like so:

```
@Autowired
UnpublishedStuffFactory unpublishedStuffFactory;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public OutputStuff update(@RequestBody Stuff stuff, @PathVariable String id) {

    UnpublishedStuff uStuff = unpublishedStuffFactory.get(stuff);
    //handle the request
}
```

UnpublishedStuffFactory.java:

```
@Component
public class UnpublishedStuffFactory {

    @Autowired
    //some autowired beans

    public UnpublishedStuff get(Stuff stuff) {
        return new UnpublishedStuff(stuff, /*some autowired beans*/);
    }
}
```

So `Stuff` is my domain object (simple POJO). `OutputStuff` is something I generate (some metadata etc) and return if `update` was ok.
It all works fine, however I would like spring to automatically execute this factory method when request comes in, and inject `UnpublishedStuff` to the `update` method, instead of injecting `Stuff`.
Basically `UnpublishedStuff` is kind of a decorator around `Stuff` that adds functionality via other autowired beans (from the factory) to validate, publish etc to `Stuff` (I do not want this functionality in `Stuff`, I want it to stay a basic POJO, hence the decorator).
Is there a way to do this? Or maybe there is a better approach to this stuff?
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Write your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which does the deserialization from JSON to `Stuff` then goes through the factory call.

Comment: Thanks, I will read up on `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and give it a go :)

Comment: Note that is not necessarily trivial. I think your current setup is fine.